# List all php files inside a folder with modification date and permissions

Tags: bash, find

I did write a script which checks all php files within a given folder for changes every hour, so I can detect possible code injections and their integrity. It's working so far, but my approach seems a little slow and forks too many `ls` processes. Here's the code:

```
/usr/bin/find /home/www -name "*.php" -exec ls -l \{} \;
```

Is there a better way?

Please note I need, at a minimum, full path, permissions, owner, group and modification time for each of the files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find has a built-in action "-ls" that should do what you need (see below). If that isn't quite the info you're after, you can also use -printf and [format directives](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Format-Directives) to control exactly what gets printed.

```
james@Brindle:/tmp/blah$ time /usr/bin/find . -name "*.php" -exec ls -l \{} \;
-rw-r--r--  1 james  wheel  0  8 Jul 08:50 ./other.php
-rw-r--r--  1 james  wheel  0  8 Jul 08:50 ./thing.php

real    0m0.015s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.008s
james@Brindle:/tmp/blah$ time find . -ls
1631212        0 drwxr-xr-x    4 james            wheel                 136  8 Jul 08:50 .
1631215        0 -rw-r--r--    1 james            wheel                   0  8 Jul 08:50 ./other.php
1631213        0 -rw-r--r--    1 james            wheel                   0  8 Jul 08:50 ./thing.php

real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.003s
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: `find /home/www/ -type f -mmin -60 -iname '*.php'`

`-type f` will speed up the check as it limits to files only.

`-mmin -60` is all files modified up to 60 minutes ago.

If you need more information you can then pipe to `xargs` with something like: `find /home/www/ -type f -mmin -60 -iname '*.php' | xargs stat`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [aide](http://aide.sourceforge.net/). It does exactly what you are describing and brings some more features.

Comment: or l5 or tripwire or afick, yafick, Artillery....

Comment: I accepted the James answer because it answers my question, but this is indeed very interesting. Thanks!